# Using variable for attribute name in Mongoose query not returning correct result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get a count of documents with a certain attribute using Mongoose, and for some reason it will not return the correct value if I use a variable inside a loop for the attribute name. For example, the below code works just fine on its own:

```
Artist.count({lyric_soprano: true}, function(err, count) {
  console.log(count);  // 17
});
```

It also works when I type in the attribute name within a loop, like so:

```
var voices = ["lyric_soprano"];

async.map(voices, function(voiceType, callback) {
  console.log(voiceType);  // "lyric_soprano"
  console.log(typeof voiceType); // String
  console.log(voiceType == "lyric_soprano");  // true
  Artist.count({lyric_soprano: true}, function(err, count) {
    console.log(count); // 17
    callback(null, count);
  });
}, function(err, results) {
  console.log(results); // [[17]]
});
```

However, when I actually use the iterator variable for the attribute name, which I need to do since I'll be doing this with a much larger list of voice types, it doesn't give me the correct answer.

```
var voices = ["lyric_soprano"];

async.map(voices, function(voiceType, callback) {
  console.log(voiceType);  // "lyric_soprano"
  console.log(typeof voiceType); // String
  console.log(voiceType == "lyric_soprano");  // true
  Artist.count({voiceType: true}, function(err, count) {
    console.log(count); // 0
    callback(null, count);
  });
}, function(err, results) {
  console.log(results); // [[0]]
});
```

Comment: Please see the below answer, and if it is helpful, kindly accept/upvote it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the code:

```
Artist.count({voiceType: true}, function(err, count) {...}
```

as,

```
var query = {};
query[voiceType] = true;
Artist.count(query, function(err, count) {...}
```

This is required because, in java script when creating an `Object` with key value pairs in it, the `keys` are coerced to `String` type.

Hence,
`{voiceType: true}` would actually be resolved to `{"voiceType": true}`, resulting in the query returning `0` records.

In contrast, When you assign a value as `query[voiceType] = true;`, the variable `voiceType` is first resolved to `lyric_soprano` and then set to the object, and resulting in the query fetching the correct number of rows.